# Sort by Date in iOS

Tags: ios

I am storing data in Sqlite Database along with the date of insertion. The date is also stored in the sqlite as String format. Is it possible to retrieve the data with sorting Date. I doubt about this, since Date is also storing as string. If this is not possible by querying, is there any way to sort NSDate.

What is the issue of down vote for this question. Because of this I am not able to post questions. Please remove the down vote. Someone who understood my question had already replied. If no one shouldn't understand this question, then why Omar Abdelhafith answered for this question. That idea also helped me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a sample of such a date-string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What comes to my mind now, is to convert all string data to Time Interval since 1970
This way time and date are easier to deal with since they are integers
Then you could do something like

```
   sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    [array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
```

Comment: Thank you Omar, I will try this and let you know. I hope this idea will work out.

Comment: It has too, i tend always to store dates as integer, its easier to store, compare and do operations on